# Por que em Portugal se diz “desporto” e no Brasil “esporte“?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas

Por que em Portugal se diz “desporto” e no Brasil “esporte”?

Comment: O que pesquisaste, CIMend? Do que encontraste, que dúvidas te ficaram?

Comment: Brasil sempre está copiando os gringos: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-palavra-desporto/19349

Comment: Uma adaptacao do ingles

Comment: Oi CIMend - se você encontrou a resposta, não hesite em responder tua própria pergunta, isso só acrescenta ao site.

Comment: Feito. De um like

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição, @ClMend. Feito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cópia do [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-palavra-desporto/19349):

> Segundo José Pedro Machado (Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguesa), a palavra desporto tem um desenvolvimento histórico com dois momentos. Por um lado, é uma adaptação do antigo francês *desport*, forma divergente de *deport*, «divertimento, jogo», derivado regressivo do verbo *déporter*, «divertir, distrair». É assim que se explica que a palavra desporto ocorra com o sentido de «divertimento»  num texto do cronista Rui de Pina (final do século XV). Paralelamente a desporto, encontramos, no português do séc. XVI, a forma deporte, adaptação do italiano *dipórto*, que já era adaptação do já referido vocábulo francês *deport* (Machado, op. cit.).
>
> No entanto, a partir do século XIX, o inglês *sport* (também derivado do francês *deport*) terá contribuído para o incremento do uso de desporto no português europeu. No português do Brasil, preferiu-se mesmo a forma inglesa e criou-se adaptação esporte (idem).

Comment: É bem difícil de ler esta resposta. Você poderia dar uma limpeza nela.

Comment: Sport , origem da lingua inglesa.. resposta revista

Comment: Ficou muito melhor. :)

Comment: Pode dar um like ?

Comment: @ClMend A resposta (v2) ainda cotinha muito material duplicado e desnecessário (e.g., todo o texto do "Quem somos" do Ciberdúvidas), e o link incluído não funcionava, pois continha um caractere incorreto. Corrigi esses pontos e "_upvotei_" a resposta, mas seria ótimo se você pudesse copiar e colar com um pouco mais de cuidado no futuro.

Comment: @Lambie, para o caso de você querer checar: essa resposta, que você apontou nos comentários da questão, está melhor formatada agora.

Comment: Mais limpa a resposta dessa forma.